# understanding a bribing function in a second bid auction with one-round bribe

Tags: proof-explanation, game-theory

In this [paper](http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/schummer/ftp/research/bbribe/bbribe2.pdf) about bribing in second price auctions, they describe a model of variable bribe, where the bribing player may decide what amount to offer to the accepting player as a function of his value

On page $16$, proposition $6$ they come to a conclusion if the bribing function $b()$ is continuous then it is the unique solution to the following ode:

$$ b'(\theta_j) = \begin{cases} \frac{F'(\theta_j + b(\theta_j))(\theta_j - b(\theta_j))}{F(\theta_j + b(\theta_j)) - F'(\theta_j +b(\theta_j))(\theta_j-b(\theta_j))} & \text{if $\theta_j+b(\theta_j) \lt 1$} \\
0 & \text{else}\end{cases} $$

They include a short explanation on why this is true, but I didn't fully understand it.
I understand each part of the equation on its own, but not sure why $b$ must satisfy this ODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the continuous equilibrium the bribing player gives away their type when bribing, the bribed player will accept exactly if $\theta_i-\theta_j\le b(\theta_j)$, or equivalently if $\theta_i\le\theta_j+b(\theta_j)$. Thus the gain that the bribing player expects from the bribe being accepted is

$$
P\left(\theta_i\le\theta_j+b(\theta_j)\right)\left(\theta_j-b(\theta_j)\right)=F\left(\theta_j+b(\theta_j)\right)\left(\theta_j-b(\theta_j)\right)\;.
$$

If we weren't dealing with a continuous equilibrium, we'd simply set the derivative of this expression with respect to $b(\theta_j)$ to zero to find the equilibrium condition

$$
F'\left(\theta_j+b(\theta_j)\right)\left(\theta_j-b(\theta_j)\right)-F\left(\theta_j+b(\theta_j)\right)=0\;.
$$

However, in the continuous equilibrium, this doesn't take into account that the bribed player is inferring the bribing player's type from the bribe. Whereas the $\theta_j$ in the gain per accepting opponent, $\theta_j-b(\theta_j)$, is the *actual* type of the bribing player, the $\theta_j$ in the probability of acceptance, $F\left(\theta_j+b(\theta_j)\right)$, is the *inferred* type of the bribing player, the type that the bribed player infers based on the bribe. The bribed player still has the same beliefs and strategy, so we need to treat this inferred $\theta_j$ as $\theta(b)$, the inverse function of $b(\theta)$ that the bribed player uses to infer the bribing player's type from the bribe. Thus, the bribing player's expected gain is

$$
F\left(\theta(b(\theta_j))+b(\theta_j)\right)\left(\theta_j-b(\theta_j)\right)\;.
$$

This leads to an additional term in the derivative with respect to $b(\theta_j)$, and the equilibrium condition becomes

$$
F'\left(\theta_j+b(\theta_j)\right)\left(\theta'(b(\theta_j))+1\right)\left(\theta_j-b(\theta_j)\right)-F\left(\theta_j+b(\theta_j)\right)=0\;.
$$

Then using $\theta'(b(\theta_j))=b'(\theta_j)^{-1}$ yields a differential equation for $b(\theta_j)$, which you can bring into the form given in the paper by solving for $b'(\theta_j)$.

*Edit:*

I'll rewrite this with more rigorous notation, since the way I wrote it above apparently left room for confusion.

So let $b(\theta_j)$ denote the function that the bribing player uses to determine the bribe in the original strategy, and let $\theta(b)$ denote its inverse, the function that the bribed player uses to infer the bribing player's type from the bribe.

To derive the equilibrium condition, we consider some fixed $\theta_0$, and we want to see whether the bribing player can gain by offering a different bribe $b_0$ at $\theta_0$ than the strategy $b(\theta_j)$ would prescribe. By the definition of an equilibrium, the bribed player's strategy remains the same, so the bribed player continues to use the function $b(\theta)$ to infer the bribing player's type from the bribe.

The bribing player's expected gain from the bribe $b_0$ being accepted is

$$
P\left(\theta_i\le\theta(b_0)+b_0\right)\left(\theta_0-b_0\right)=F\left(\theta(b_0)+b_0\right)\left(\theta_0-b_0\right)\;.
$$

Here $\theta_0-b_0$ is the bribing player's gain per accepting player; we have to use the actual type $\theta_0$ since the bribing player calculates knowing her own type. By contrast, $\theta_i\le\theta(b_0)+b_0$ is the acceptance condition for the bribed player, and here we have to use the inferred type $\theta(b_0)$, since the bribed player calculates with this inferred type and doesn't know the actual type of the bribing player.

Setting the derivative with respect to $b_0$ to zero yields

$$
F'\left(\theta(b_0)+b_0\right)\left(\theta'(b_0)+1\right)\left(\theta_0-b_0\right)-F\left(\theta(b_0)+b_0\right)=0\;.
$$

This condition must hold at $b_0=b(\theta_0)$, so we substitute that into the equation,

$$
F'\left(\theta(b(\theta_0))+b(\theta_0)\right)\left(\theta'(b(\theta_0))+1\right)\left(\theta_0-b(\theta_0)\right)-F\left(\theta(b(\theta_0))+b(\theta_0)\right)=0\;,
$$

and then we use the fact that $\theta$ is the inverse of $b$ and thus $\theta(b(\theta_0))=\theta_0$:

$$
F'\left(\theta_0+b(\theta_0)\right)\left(\theta'(b(\theta_0))+1\right)\left(\theta_0-b(\theta_0)\right)-F\left(\theta_0+b(\theta_0)\right)=0\;.
$$

Since the fixed $\theta_0$ that we picked was arbitrary, we can now replace it with the general $\theta_j$, yielding the equilibrium condition as a differential equation:

$$
F'\left(\theta_j+b(\theta_j)\right)\left(\theta'(b(\theta_j))+1\right)\left(\theta_j-b(\theta_j)\right)-F\left(\theta_j+b(\theta_j)\right)=0\;.
$$

Comment: could you please explain what do you mean by "Changing $b(\theta_j)$ only at a single...so we need to treat this inferred $\theta_j$ as $\theta(b)$" , also I dont understand why would $\theta(b)$ the inverse function of $b(\theta)$ would be different then $\theta_j$, the bribed player can infer $\theta_j$ from the bribe

Comment: @DanielKatzan: On your first point: That was actually badly argued; I've edited it. We only have to consider whether the bribing player can improve, given the bribed player's strategy, so I don't have to argue that the bribed player's strategy doesn't change. Given that the bribed player's strategy doesn't change, he uses the inverse function $b(\theta)$ to infer the bribing player's type. On your second point: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question correctly (it's a bit garbled), but I'll try to answer it. The bribed player uses $b(\theta)$ to infer the bribing player's type.

Comment: If the bribing player applies the original strategy, then the bribed player always correctly infers the type. However, we're now considering a change in the bribing player's strategy without a change in the bribed player' strategy. That is, we're considering whether the bribing player can gain by offering a different bribe at $\theta_j$; but the bribed player still interprets that bribe the same way, and thus infers not the actual $\theta_j$ but the $\theta_j$ that leads to this bribe according to the unmodified function $b(\theta_j)$. I hope that's made it a bit clearer?

Comment: so why do you omit $\theta(b(\theta_j)$ in some places and just write $\theta_j$, shouldn't the derivative be $F'\left(\theta(b(\theta_j))+b(\theta_j)\right)\left(\theta'(b(\theta_j))+1\right)\left(\theta_j-b(\theta_j)\right)-F\left(\theta(b(\theta_j))+b(\theta_j)\right)=0\;.$

Comment: also why can we change the bribing player strategy while the bribed player strategy stays the same, the bribed player assumes the bribing player is rational, and the bribing player is rational if he plays by the second equation in your answer.

Comment: @DanielKatzan: To address your first question above, I expanded the answer with a new version of the derivation with more rigorous notation. I hope that clarifies why we can write $b_j$ where you have $\theta(b(\theta_j))$ when we're done differentiating.

Comment: To address your second question above: That's just the definition of an equilibrium. I'm not thoroughly familiar with the concept of a sequential equilibrium used in the paper, but I looked it up in the reference they give and it seems like a more refined version of a Nash equilibrium in the context of games with incomplete information, with the same basic idea that we have an equilibrium if neither player can gain by deviating from the strategy profile, assuming that the other player sticks to the strategy profile.